# How can I invoke Ruby from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, execjs

There are several ways for running JavaScript inside of a Ruby script. For example, there is ExecJS which is frequently used for porting NPM modules to Ruby. So, is there a "ExecRuby" for Node?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can invoke Ruby like any other shell command using [`child_process.exec()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/child_processes.html#child_process.exec)

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

exec('ruby -e "puts \'Hello from Ruby!\'"', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Don't know if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: That's true, of course. But I'm looking for a NPM module or something similar, which handles the bridge. Just like ExecJS does in Ruby. If there aren't library for this I guess it wouldn't be too hard to port ExecJS to Node and turn it around.