# how to execute a command line in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, actionhero

I am using the [actionhero](http://www.actionherojs.com/docs/ops/getting-started.html) framework, it can be started by command `actionhero start`. but the problem is that, my cloud node.js app runner can only run an app by specify a main file, such as index.js. How can I adapt my app to be started by a normal node.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two choices**

**Choice #1**
You can use `child_process` to execute any shell from your node.js application. See this [How can I invoke Ruby from Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101137/how-can-i-invoke-ruby-from-node-js) as a reference. This method is a native node.js way. You don't need to install any external npm.

**Choice #2**
Use `shelljs` to execute such command. (https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs) The way it allows you execute the command is quite similar to using `child_process` but it makes your code a little neater.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at something like...

```
'use strict';
let child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.execFile('node', [`.\path\to\actionhero`, `start`], (err) => {
  if(err) console.log(err);
});
```